# vertical toolStrip position last item at the bottom

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a tool strip docked to the left and I want to make one button to be on the buttom of the toolStrip. Any tips how to do that ?

[image: this is what i'm trying to do]

I tried to put a panel insted of the toolStrip and dock the panel to the left, add the toolstrip (without the logout button) to the panel, and then add a new logout button to the leftPanel.
Didnt work well

Answer (score 4):

You can change *Alignment* Property of ToolStripItem to *Right*
Like

```
toolStripButton3.Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Right;
```

[image]